# Dynamically Adding DIVs widgets inside another DIV widget in apostrophe-cms

Tags: css, apostrophe-cms

I have built two widgets in Apostrophe CMS :

Multi-Column Widget which has the flexbox class applied and serves up an Add-column widget which in turn serves up richtext, etc that is intended to flex out with however many Add-Columns inserted into the Multi-Column widget. Problem is it all gets a bit funky. The editor UI goes a bit insane with a horizontal layout, drag and drop sometimes duplicates and looses content, you have to really try hard to understand what is being selected.

Is there any tools or tips on working with this type of layout?

```
index.js for multiple-column widget
======================================
module.exports = {
extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',
label: 'Multiple Column Layout',
contextualOnly: true,
addFields: [
    {
      name: 'multiColContainer',
      type: 'area',
      label: 'Multiple Column Container',
    }
  ]
};

widget.html for multiple-column-widget
======================================
<div class="multiple-column">
  {{ apos.area(data.widget, 'multiColContainer', {
        widgets: {

    'add-column': {}
        }
    }) }}

</div>

index.js for add-column-widget
==============================
module.exports = {
extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',
label: 'Add Column',
contextualOnly: true,
addFields: [
{
  name: 'addColumn',
  type: 'area',
  label: 'Column',
}
]
};

widget.html for add-column-widget
=================================
    <div class="add-column">
    {{ apos.area(data.widget, 'addColumn', {
        widgets: {
            'apostrophe-images': {},
            'link': {},
            'apostrophe-video':{},
            'apostrophe-rich-text': {
            toolbar: [ 'Styles', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Table', 'BulletedList', 'Blockquote', 'Strike',  'Subscript', 'Superscript'],
            styles: [
                { name: 'Heading', element: 'h1' },
                { name: 'Subheading', element: 'h2' },
                { name: 'Title', element: 'h3' },
                { name: 'Small Title', element: 'h4' },
                { name: 'Paragraph', element: 'p' }
                ]
            }
        }
    }) }}
</div>

changes to site.less for displaying flex and to help out during editing
=======================================================================
.multiple-column {
  .apos-area-widgets, // proper context for logged-in user
  .apos-area { // proper context for logged-out user
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
 }

.apos-area-widget-wrapper {
   flex-grow: 1;
   flex-basis: 0;
  }

}
// try and help to identify what is what
.multiple-column {
  .apos-area-widgets{
    :hover{border:1px dashed red;}

  .add-column{
    :hover{border:1px dashed greenyellow;}
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: I think the short answer is 'keep doing what you're doing'. Changing the flow of widgets/areas/dropzones just needs to be bashed through with admin ui specific css overrides. If you can turn on `blockLevelControls: true` in your outer area you can start to get some separation. Other than that you should probably give some padding to the multi column widget itself to separate its controls when logged in. You can do some specific control positioning with https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/adding-editable-content-to-pages.html#take-control-of-your-controls

Comment: It seems useful to have an npm module that activates a container and child widget set where all this css is worked out but makes no assumptions about what kind of content you're going to put into the child widgets